# Setting onblur and onfocus attributes for textbox created programatically?

Tags: vb.net, textbox, onblur, onfocus

How do I put the onblur and onfocus attributes on a textbox created programatically?

Here's my code -

```
td = New HtmlTableCell
td.Style.Add("padding-bottom", "5px")
Dim txtbox As New TextBox
txtbox.Style.Add("width", "96%")
txtbox.ID = "ename"
td.Controls.Add(txtbox)
tr.Cells.Add(td)
td.Style.Add("padding-top", "5px")
```

Now I want to add onblur and onfocus. is there something like? --

```
txtbox.attributes.Add("onblur","Enter Name")
txtbox.attributes.Add("onfocus","")
```

I tried this and doesn't work.  Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

onblur and onfocus are JavaScript event handlers.  Their values must be valid JavaScript.  You're probably looking for something like this:

```
txtbox.attributes.Add("onblur","this.value = 'Enter Name';")
txtbox.attributes.Add("onfocus","this.value = '';")
```